# How to check the checkbox in filament edit page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

In the example of title and slug inputs, which whenever something is written in title, will be written in slug.

But I want to have a checkbox that determines whether it should automatically write(convert) to slug input or not.

```php
TextInput::make('title')
    ->reactive()
    ->afterStateUpdated(static::fillSlug(...))
    ->required(),

TextInput::make('slug')
    ->disabled(fn (callable $get) => $get('fill slug based on title'))
    ->required(),

Checkbox::make('fill slug based on title')
    ->default(true)
    ->inline(false)
    ->reactive()
    ->afterStateUpdated(static::fillSlug(...))
    ->dehydrated(false),
```

> `fillSlug` sets slug if checkbox is checked

The problem:

It works on create page, but on edit page checkbox is not checked. How can I check the checkbox?
I've tried `->extraAttributes(['checked' => 'true'])` but that doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

->formatStateUsing(fn () => true)
or getting the $state
->formatStateUsing(fn ($state) => !$state ? true : $state)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).